# How to update tableViewCells in firstVC in realtime when secondVC is updated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, real-time, updates

I am currently in a bit of a trouble. I am creating a simple task manager. The user sets reminder in the secondVC and a bell icon is shown in the tableviewcell in firstVC for the appropriate cell. Now when you tap the cell and you move to secondVC, code is invoked in viewDidLoad() that compares the time_set for that task to the current time and says 'Time's Up' if current time is more than time_set. This then updates the icon and removes it from the cell in the firstVC.

However, I want the cells in the firstVC to be updated without first tapping in the cell and invoking code in viewDidLoad(). Is there any way I can run a function in the secondVC continuously and if a change occurs, then in realtime update the tableViewCell?

Comment: Use a `Timer` to periodically invoke your check function and reload the relevant rows of your table view. You will hiur second view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 will try it out!